# Implicit Derivation. Approximation for $f(0.01)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Let $y=f(x)$ be the function described implicitly by 
$$y\cos x = e^x \ln y + e - 1$$

Give an approximation for $f(0.01)$. You do not need to simplify your
answer.

How to give an approximation here? I have solved for $y'$. Thanks.

Comment: y' is dy/dx here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$f(0.01)\approx f(0)+f'(0)(0.01-0)=...$$